# Renaming multiple similar column names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rename, names

I have a data frame that has columns ranging from start_1 to start_32. I'd like to rename all of them to m1 to m32. So far I have done this using the following code:

```
df %>%
  rename(m1 = start_1,
         m2 = start_2,
         ...
         m32 = start_32)
```

I may need to do this a few more times for other variables and I am looking for more condensed way of achieving the same goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `names`:

```r
names(df) <- gsub("^start_", "m", names(df))
```

---

or, in `dplyr`, with `rename_with`:

```r
library(dplyr)
rename_with(df, ~ gsub("start_", "m", .x), starts_with("start_"))
rename_with(df, ~ gsub("^start_", "m", .x))
```